# Kernel of $k[a,b]\to k[r^3,r^4], \;\;f(a,b)\mapsto f(r^3,r^4)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field, let $k[r^3,r^4]$ be a subalgebra of $k[r]$, and define the map
$$
\varphi:k[a,b]\to k[r^3,r^4],\quad f(a,b)\mapsto f(r^3,r^4).
$$
I want to show $\ker(\varphi)=(a^4-b^3)$. If $f(a,b)\in (a^4-b^3)$, then $f(a,b)=g(a,b)\cdot(a^4-b^3)$ for some $g(a,b)\in k[a,b]$. Then $$f(r^3,r^4)=g(r^3,r^4)\cdot((r^3)^4-(r^4)^3)=g(r^3,r^4)\cdot(r^{12}-r^{12})=g(r^3,r^4)\cdot0=0,$$
so $f(a,b)\in\ker(\varphi)$. I am stuck on the reverse direction. If I let $h(a,b)\in\ker(\varphi)$, then I know that $h(r^3,r^4)=0$. But where can I go from here? We need to show that $h(a,b)$ is a $k[a,b]$-multiple of $a^4-b^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $\alpha\in\ker\varphi$ we may subtract off some multiple of $(a^4-b^3)$ to attain an element of the form:$$p_0(a)+p_1(a)b+p_2(a)b^2,$$
where $p_0,p_1,p_2$ are polynomials over $k$.

We know that $$p_0(r^3)+p_1(r^3)r^4+p_2(r^3)r^8=0.$$

$p_0(r^3)$ is a $k$-linear combination of $r^i$ with $i\equiv 0 \mod 3$.

$p_1(r^3)r^4$ is a $k$-linear combination of $r^i$ with $i\equiv 1 \mod 3$.

$p_2(r^3)r^8$ is a $k$-linear combination of $r^i$ with $i\equiv 2 \mod 3$.

Thus no monomial $r^i$ occurs in more than one of the above.  However it cannot occur in just one as the sum of the three terms above is $0$.
We conclude that $p_0=p_1=p_2=0$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the last bit? Why is $p_0=p_1=p_2=0$? I don't understand what you mean with the congruence class part.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow Each monomial $r^i$ can occur in at most one of the three terms.  (Which one depends on $i \mod 3$).Therefore the coefficient on $r^i$ in that term must be $0$.

Comment: I understand. Also, just out of curiosity, the part about subtracting off a multiple of $(a^4-b^3)$ is just the multivariate division algorithm, yes?

Comment: @MichaelMorrow It is much simpler than that:  We can regard $\alpha$ as a polynomial in one variable $b$, with coefficients in $k[a]$, so it is just high school polynomial division.  Note this is works because of the fact that the coefficient on the highest power of $b$ in $a^4-b^3$ is just $-1\in k$.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow As someone who is often finding generators for kernels (usually over non-commutative rings), I find this approach very effective: Subtract multiples of the (conjectured) generators from an arbitrary element of the kernel, to get into a "standard form" of some kind.  Then show that any element of the kernel which can be written in that standard form is in fact $0$ (or sometimes an obvious linear combination of the conjectured generators).